# How to initialize a specific subclass in a loop?

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a class called Operator with multiple subclasses, each subclass has a variable that identifies it. I have a method in another class that returns a new instance of one of those subclasses of operator depending on the variable, I want to know if there's a optimized way to initialize and return the specific subclass dependig of the case.

**Operator class**

```
public abstract class Operator {
private String logic;
private String formula;

public Operador(String logic, String formula) {
    this.logic = logic;
    this.formula = formula;
}
//Some methods
}
```

**Some of the subclasses**

**Conjuncion class**

```
public class Conjuncion extends Operador {

public Conjuncion() {
    super("and", "&");
}
//Some methods
}
```

**Disjunction Class**

```
public class Disjunction extends Operador{

public Disjunction() {
    super("or", "@");
}
//Some methods
}
```

In another class I have a method called **selectOperator** that returns one of the subclasses of Operator if some conditions are met

```
private Operator selectOperator(String str) {
    Operator operator = null;
    switch (str) {
    case "&":
        operator = new Conjuncion();
        break;
    case "@":
        operator = new Disjunction();
        break;
    case "-":
        operator = new Negacion();
        break;
    //More cases
    }
    return operator;
}
```

My question is can I have something like this?

```
for(int = i; i < numberOfSubclasses; i++){
        if(str.equals(subclass.getLogic)) {
            return Operator operator = new SubClass();
        }
    }
```

I'm pretty new with OOP, so this could be a lot of help for a newbie, if you have another advice about anything else in my code, it'd help too.

By the way, if any variable or class name does not match is because my code is in spanish and I translated the it for the question.

Comment: actually, yes you can. what you are asking for, is something called `algebraic data type`, or in OO world, `object algebra`.  https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-31057-7_2 . another alternative in typical OO practice is  visitor pattern. you can take a look at both.

Comment: though i have to say, algebraic data type is some type of concept that go against typical OO mindset, and very often a good portion of OO programmers would tell you not to do.

Comment: If the number of subclasses is clearly defined, using an enum may be a good idea.

Comment: Do all operators implement the same methods? Do they have any mutable state?

Comment: I wanted to for it to be possible to add more subclasses in the future, so I don't know.

Comment: They have the same methods with different implementations, I don't really know what you mean by mutable state, sorry, I'm pretty new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you want to get rid of all the switch cases, and therefore use a for-loop that handles the situation, by checking what is the operator.getLogic() and use that to pass the right sub class.

So **if** my assumption is correct you cannot check it the way your classes and your constructors are right now. 
What you can do is create a List that contains all of the operators you use, and for each object in that list, get its logic with:

```
ArrayList<Operators> operators_list = new ArrayList<Operators>();
//put all of your operators inside that list
```

Use a for loop like:

```
for(int i=0; i<operators_list.size(); i++) {

     if(str.equals(operators_list.get(i).getLogic() {
     //create the subclass according to what the value of the current
     //getLogic() is, and call that as a super()
     }
}
```

But a quick answer to your question is a *NO*.